# Adding the specified count to the semaphore would cause it to exceed its maximum count

Tags: c#-4.0

Adding the specified count to the semaphore would cause it to exceed its maximum count. This error is occurring sometime. Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you post a minimal test case which shows your problem? There isn't enough detail in your question for anyone to give you a helpful answer at the moment.

Comment: The error message says exactly what is wrong. The semaphore was created with a maximum count. You are exceeding that maximum.

Comment: This is, with 100% fidelity, an exception that tells you that you've got a bug in your code.  The contract for Semaphore requires you to call its Release() method **exactly** as often as its Wait method.  You called Release() too often, that's a bug.